# Express a vector in terms of his projections

Tags: vectors

How can I express the projection of a vector over another vector as a linear combination of the projections of the first vector on the axis?

Referring to the image, I need to express the projection of the vector $\vec{S}$ over vector $\vec{B}$ as a linear combination of the projections of $\vec{S}$ on axis $x$ and $z$ namely $S_x$ and $S_z$.

[image]

Comment: Vector $\vec{S}$ projected on $\vec{B}$ is $\frac{(\vec{S}\cdot\vec{B})}{(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{B})}\vec{B}$. If you express the scalar product $(\vec{S}\cdot\vec{B})$ in terms of $S_x,S_y$ I think you are done. No ?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, but I don't know how to do it. Is it $S_{\theta}=(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{B})\vec{B}=S_{\theta}cos(\pi/2-\theta)\hat{S_x}+S_{\theta}sin(\pi/2-\theta)\hat{S_z}$ so that $S_{\theta}=S_{\theta}sin(\theta)\hat{S_x}+S_{\theta}cos(\theta)\hat{S_z}$?

Comment: Where did your components of $\vec{B}$ go ? You let them disappear ? I would use the standard definition of the scalar product $(\vec{S}\cdot\vec{B})=S_xB_x+S_zB_z$ .

Comment: @KurtG. Your solution seems right to me but the solution I have is $S_{\theta}=S_xsin(\theta)+S_zcos(\theta)$

Comment: $S_xsin(\theta)+S_zcos(\theta)$ can only be a number. What is $S_\theta$ ? Judging from your first comment you want it to be a vector parallel to $\vec{B}$. If so your "solution" is a contradicton in itself.